# How to print content of responseXpath () in REST::Client module

Tags: perl, rest, xpath, xml-libxml

I'm using [REST::Client](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?REST%3a%3aClient) perl module to test my REST server. I want to print REST response as usual xml

Currently I'm using

```
print $client->responseContent()
```

which prints xml in one line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><ns2:messageReference xmlns:ns2="urn:com:test:xml:rest:mds:1"><messageId>775775</messageId></ns2:messageReference>
```

The `REST::Client` module also returns xpath context for the body content by `$client->responseXpath()`, but I cannot find a way to use it with `toString()` function from `XML::LibXML`, which allows to print it as I want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <ns2:messageReference xmlns:ns2="urn:com:test:xml:rest:mds:1">
    <messageId>775775</messageId>
  </ns2:messageReference>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*$client->responseContent()* outputs the response as is, if you would like to beautify it use XML::LibXML

```
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(string => $client->responseContent());
print $dom->toString();
```

Comment: I get the following error:    Can't locate object method "load_xml" via package "XML::LibXML" at....

Comment: I implemented solution in another way:     my $parser=XML::LibXML->new();
 my $doc =$parser->parse_string($client->responseContent());
 print "\n" . $doc->toString(1);